# Check the cause of slow loading time among different server

Tags: linux, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, performance

A e-shop has developed using perstashop and put to the three server:

the first 2 are amazon EC2, should be same setting

Server 1: http://be-pure.com/en/women/3-slim-y-tank.html

Server 2: http://52.77.216.83/en/women/3-slim-y-tank.html

the last one is just local hosting

Server 3: http://internal001.zizsoft.com/be_pure/en/women/3-slim-y-tank.html

The problem is server 1 loading very slow compare to the other two server, but the performance should be the best among 3. The speed should be 1>2>3, however, it turn out to be 2>1>3

From http://tools.pingdom.com/ , I suspect that the server 1 need around 10s before it actually start download the file, while server 2 start at 3s, which make a huge difference

Also, when running a http://www.monitis.com/traceroute/ it looks like it doesn't make it all the way to the destination, seems like some sort of network issue.

What takes the long load time for server 1? Just consider it as an PHP site, any ways to check why it is slow?

Thanks a lot for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its Amazon hardware problems you can try stop and start the server, 
so you get spawn on different hardware.

Your security settings (or Amazon by default) are blocking SYN packets and traceroute is unable to finish. Enable TCP to see results

```
 sudo traceroute -T be-pure.com
```

If hardware is not the problem, something about your server configuration. Do you notice anything on error logs?

Answer (score 2):

The main cause of your site to load slow is the amount of static content (CSS,JS,Image) you have on your pages. Your home page size and http://be-pure.com/en/women/3-slim-y-tank.html link is too big and it send approx 226 request for that single page. This page contains too many images and js which take time to load. Also I can see there is no Cache mechanism on your sever end. Every time it is been serve from origin server.

Few points to improve this:-

1. Cache your static content on both server end and browser end.
2. Reduce Image size by compression or deflating
3. Use CDN (CloudFlare). This will  boost your network performance and will help in maintaining cache also.
4. You can use PHP-FPM on server side to improve php performance.

Answer (score 0):

As someone else pointed out, if it is "slow hardware", you can just restart your server to run in on different one. But I doubt that's the issue.

The main thing seems to be with your page itself. It has a ton of content on it and should be optimized before even thinking about server optimization.

Check this [Google PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fbe-pure.com%2Fen%2Fwomen%2F3-slim-y-tank.html) site. This helps you debug the problems with your web page. The main problems seem to be:

- Not minimized CSS/JS
- Blocking JS content
- Uncompressed images
- No cache

Do those, and if that doesn't work out for you, start looking for problems on the server side. To help you with that we need to know about the server. What OS, which web server, PHP, database is it running?